# If R is an integral domain then (R,+) is NOT isomorphic to (U(R),*)

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, solution-verification, integral-domain, ring-isomorphism

If $R$ is an integral domain, then $(R,+)$ is NOT isomorphic to $(U(R),*).$

That is, the additive group of an integral domain is not isomorphic to the group of units of the domain.

I tried to prove it, but I'm not very sure about the validity of my proof:

For the sake of argument, assume there is an isomorphism.

If $|R|=n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $|U(R)| \leq n-1$ because zero (identity element wrt addition) is not in the units since $0r=r0=0$ for every $r \in R.$

But this contradicts the fact that there is a bijection. Hence we conclude that there is no isomorphism in the case when $R$ is finite.

***The following is false but I want to fix it and I don't know how.***

Now assume $R$ is infinite, and suppose $\phi: (U(R),*) \rightarrow (R,+) $ is isomorphism.

Then $\phi(ab)= \phi(a)+\phi(b)$ and $\phi(1)=0$.

Therefore if $r \in (U(R),*),$ then so $r^{-1}$.

Let $r$ be arbitrary, then $\phi(1) = \phi(rr^{-1}) = \phi(r) + \phi(r^{-1}) = 0$

So $\phi(r) = - \phi(r^{-1}) \Rightarrow \phi(r) = \phi((r^{-1})^{-1}) $

Since $\phi$ is isomorphism, then $r=r^{-1}$.

But $r$ was arbitrary, and thence we get a contradiction.

I need to fix this

**Another "proof" to the infinite case:**

If the characteristic is zero:

$0 =\phi(1)=\phi(-1(-1))=\phi(-1)+\phi(-1)=2 \phi(-1) \Rightarrow  \phi(-1)=0$ but as $\phi$ is 1-1 then $-1=1$, contradiction.

If the characteristic is not zero I don't know what to do.

Comment: You can't make the claim $\phi(r)=-\phi(r^{-1})\Rightarrow \phi(r)=\phi(-r^{-1})$ because, $\phi$ being a homomorphism $(U(R),\cdot)\to (R,+)$, the identity for the inverse is $-\phi(x)=\phi(x^{-1})$.

Comment: @Gae. S. Yes, you are right. Stupid mistake. Do you have any idea how to proceed on the infinite case? I just want a hint.

Comment: Your work isn't correct. The fourth to last line is correct now, so don't change it anymore. The third to last line is wrong, for the reason I said in the previous comment (except that now you are making the other mistake).

Comment: @Gae. S. Yes, the implication I did is wrong. Thank you for that. Now I just need to find the contradiction in the infinite case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi:R^*\to R$ be a group isomorphism. Let's prove that $1+1=0$. In fact, if $1+1\ne0$, then $0=\phi(1)=\phi((-1)^2)=(1+1)\phi(-1)$, and therefore $\phi(-1)=0=\phi(1)$. Therefore, $-1=1$ as well. Therefore $1+1=0$.

Then, for all $x\in R^*$, we have $\phi(x^2)=\phi(x)+\phi(x)=0$. Therefore $x^2=1$ for all $x\in R^*$. But this means $(x-1)(x+1)=0$, i.e. $(x-1)^2=0$. Therefore, $x=1$.

This means that $R^*=\{1\}$. Since the zero ring isn't a domain, $\lvert R\rvert\ge2>\lvert R^*\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you. I did approach it the same way you did at the beginning, but man, I did not know how to proceed after that (check the question I updated it). Thanks again.