# Are the groups $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ and $(\Bbb R, +)$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Are the groups $(\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ and $(\Bbb R, +)$ isomorphic?

I think not, but I'm not sure how to show it. If $\varphi : (\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot) \to (\Bbb R, +)$ is an isomorphism, then it's surjective and $\varphi(1)= 0$.

I also have the existence of $\varphi^{-1} : (\Bbb R, +) \to (\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$ such that $\varphi \circ \varphi^{-1} = id_{\Bbb R}$ and $\varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi = id_{\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}}$.

Now since $\varphi^{-1}(0)=1$ I think I get a contradiction from $$\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(0))=\varphi(1)=0$$ but $$\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(1))=\varphi^{-1}(0)=1$$ so $\varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi \ne id_{\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}}$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4134827/if-r-is-an-integral-domain-then-r-is-not-isomorphic-to-ur), for $R=\Bbb R$, or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080499/existence-of-a-group-isomorphism-between-mathbb-k-and-mathbb-k-times) for $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Do you know that two isomorphic groups share exactly same no of elements of same order? Hint: additive group of reals have no elements of order $2$

Comment: Does $\Bbb{R},+$ have an element of order $2$ ? But what about $(-1)^{2}$?